# Encode string variable to UTF-16LE base64 using Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm looking to encode a string variable to UTF-16LE and base64 , the problem is that I find nothing about how to do UTF-16LE in Delphi.

Example in Python :

```
from base64 import b64encode
b64encode('my text'.encode('UTF-16LE'))
```

Example in Ruby :

```
require "base64"
Base64.encode64('my text'.force_encoding('UTF-16LE'))
```

As I can do this in Delphi?

Updated :

```
procedure TFormTest.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dest, src: TEncoding;
  srcBytes, destBytes: TBytes;
  Encoder: TIdEncoderMime;
begin
  Encoder := TIdEncoderMime.Create(nil);
  src := TEncoding.Unicode;
  srcBytes := src.GetBytes(Edit1.Text);
  Edit2.Text := Encoder.EncodeBytes(srcBytes);
  FreeAndNil(Encoder);

end;
```

Is a valid base64 UTF-16LE created?

Powershell tells me it is invalid

Command to use :

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://localhos/update_program.exe','updater.exe'); Start-Process 'updater.exe'
```

Output error :

```
Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
```

Comment: In Delphi versions 2009 and above, strings **are** in UTF-16LE. You want a method to do B64 encoding. You can probably find something in one of the Indy units.

Comment: Delphi is little-endian, and 'UTF-16LE' is default Delphi encoding for strings.

Comment: `TEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str)` to encode as UTF-16LE. Then use one of the many base64 encoders. Try some websearch.

Comment: My new source is a valid base64 UTF-16LE ?

Comment: A program tells me it is invalid

Comment: @MattOlsen what program are you using? What error is it actually saying? You need to be more specific

Comment: PowerShell -encodeCommand

Comment: @MattOlsen again, what is the actual error? And what is the value of the `String ` that you are encoding?

Comment: @MattOlsen that error suggests your original command text is invalid to begin with, not the base64 encoded version of fit. Powershell is decoding the base64 and then failing to execute the command. There are plenty of questions on StackOverflow related to "missing expression" errors.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem because the same command is used with the version of python and works well when using powershell -encodeCommand, I think in delphi something changes ...

Comment: Also i try with : echo "hi" , and get the same error

Comment: A lot of confusion here. Your original code actually worked. This question should probably be removed.

Comment: @MattOlsen: your text is valid UTF-16LE, but it is not base64 encoded, as far as I can see. You need code that turns your UTF-16LE text into base64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have shown is technically correct. The `String` gets encoded to a UTF-16LE byte array first, and then the bytes get base64 encoded.

Since you are calling `TIdEncoderMIME.Create()` to create an object instance, you should be using the `Encode()` instance method instead of the `EncodeBytes()` static method (which creates another instance internally):

```
procedure TFormTest.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Encoder: TIdEncoderMIME;
begin
  Encoder := TIdEncoderMIME.Create(nil);
  // prior to Indy 10.6.0, use TIdTextEncoding.Unicode
  // instead of IndyTextEncoding_UTF16LE...
  Edit2.Text := Encoder.Encode(Edit1.Text, IndyTextEncoding_UTF16LE);
  Encoder.Free;
end;
```

Which can be simplified further using the `EncodeString()` static method:

```
procedure TFormTest.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // prior to Indy 10.6.0, use TIdTextEncoding.Unicode
  // instead of IndyTextEncoding_UTF16LE...
  Edit2.Text := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(Edit1.Text, IndyTextEncoding_UTF16LE);
end;
```

But either way, the output is all the same. So any problem you are still having has to be elsewhere.  But you have not provided any details about how you are validating the data,  what tools are rejecting it, what errors are actually being reported, etc.

Comment: thanks for the help , that version of delphi begins to appear "IndyTextEncoding_UTF16LE" ? , because I call the unit IdGlobal but "IndyTextEncoding_UTF16LE" is missing

Comment: @MattOlsen it was added in Indy 10.6.0.0 (shipped with XE4), when [`TIdTextEncoding` was replaced with `IIdTextEncoding`](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20130423.aspx). You can upgrade XE2 to the latest Indy version, or just use `TIdTextEncoding.Unicode` instead of `IndyTextEncoding_UTF16LE `.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: `FreeAndNil`, honestly? `Encoder` will leave scope immediately after that, so there is no need to nil the reference.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis it was a copy/paste from the OP's code. On the other hand, by your reaction, should we call `Destroy` instead of `Free` to avoid the check for `nil`, too?

Comment: No, we should call `Free`, and `Free` only. More about that issue in the Embarcadero forums.

Comment: David: I strongly disagree. Everything is wrong with it. There is absolutely no need to nil something that will go out of scope directly afterward. There is actually hardly ever a need to use `FreeAndNil`, and here, there certainly isn't Note that the use of `FreeAndNil` is a code smell. Most code that needs it often is code that doesn't manage object lifetime properly.

Comment: I object to pointless `Assigned` tests. Such tests should hardly ever be necessary. And I agree that the lack of `try-finally` is an issue.

Comment: Even more than to pointless Assigned checks, I object to having to think twice. Sure, sometimes it makes sense to use Destroy instead of Free, but that is not often. So, it is part of a good habit to always use Free, even if, seldom, it is not necessary. We both know why Free should be called. But FreeAndNil is something totally different. It is hardly ever useful. Actually, if it is used a lot, it smells of bad lifetime handling. I don't think I have **any** code that needs or uses it. OTOH, Free makes sense in, I think, 99% of the code. So it a good habit to use Free instead of Destroy.

Comment: In other words: Free is necessary so often that it makes a lot of sense to use it always. That beats having to think (with the risk of being wrong) **each time again** if you can use Destroy or if you must use Free. Using Free is a good habit, even if there are some unnecessary nil checks. But code that must use FreeAndNil and must often check for Assigned is badly written code, often a sign that the author is insecure about or simple unaware of proper lifetime handling. Proper lifetime handling does't need Assigned a lot, and it should hardly ever need FreeAndNil, if at all.

Comment: Guys, this is not the place for this kind of discussion. It has *nothing* to do with the question at hand (base64'ing a UTF-16LE string). My original comment was meant to be sarcastic, not spark a debate.  Enough said..

Comment: Fwiw, I don't know if *that* is Remy's point. My proclamations are not inconsistent. Always using Free is consistent. Consistency is more important than the occasional "pointless" nil check as done by Free. So while I dislike pointless nil checks, I even more dislike **having to decide** whether to use Free or Destroy **each and every time**. OTOH, I don't have to decide whether to use FreeAndNil, because I don't need it, and Assigned only in some situations. That is because I consistently manage my memory and lifetime, no need to check whether a pointer under my control is invalid or nil.

Comment: @Remy: agreed with that.

Comment: Of course I have encountered it. I just don't like it very much, because of the **constant** need to check for nil.

Comment: How does one move to chat?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: You can't move to chat until StackOverflow detects a lot of comment activity, then it automatically provides a link to move to chat. That link has not appeared yet. It probably should have by now. I say just stop altogether. If you and David want to keep debating this, take it somewhere else, not on StackOverflow. There have been plenty of debates on this topic on the Embarcadero forums.

Comment: @Remy: indeed, this has been discussed there, ad nauseam. I side with people like Allen Bauer, Nick Hodges and Dalija Prasnikar, on this subject. I just don't need dependency injection (like Nick does) to achieve what I want.